# I want a javascript code for cloning a select box in a table in html and not in JQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a bill page for my departmental store project. I need a javascript code to have a clone of my first row which I want to have select box to choose an ID for products and categories. I am not getting a correct select box instead a input text box(similiarly). So please help me out. I am new to this discussion. I am waiting for answers. Thank you!!!...

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
    width: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="POItablediv">
  <input type="button" id="addPOIbutton" value="Add POIs" /><br/><br/>
  <table id="POITable" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Product ID</td>
      <td>Category ID</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Number Of Products</td>
      <td>Cart Price</td>
      <td>Delete Product</td>
      <td>Add Product</td>
      <td>Calculate Cart Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="pid" name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="Add More POIs" onclick="insRow()" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="calculte" value="calculate" onclick="calculate(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </table>
<script>
function deleteRow(row) {
  var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
}

function calculate(row) {
  var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById('lat').deleteRow(i);
}
function insRow() {
  var x = document.getElementById('POITable');
  var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
  var len = x.rows.length;
  new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

  var first = document.getElementById('pid');
  var options = first.innerHTML;
  var inp1=document.createElement('select');
  var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select');
  //inp1=document.createElement('select');
  var options=inp1.innerHTML+options;
  inp1.innerHTML=options;
  alert(options);
  alert(inp1);


/*  
    selectList.appendChild(option);
}*/  
 /* var all_select = document.getElementsById("pid");
  alert(all_select);
  new_row.cells[1].createElement("select");
  for (i = 0; i < all_select.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = all_select[i];
    option.text = all_select[i];
}*/
  var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp2.id += len;
  inp2.value = '';
    alert("HELLO");
  var inp3 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp1.id += len;
  inp1.value = '';
  var inp4 = new_row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp2.id += len;
  inp2.value = '';
  var inp5 = new_row.cells[5].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp1.id += len;
  inp1.value = '';
  var inp6 = new_row.cells[6].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp2.id += len;
  inp2.value = '';
  x.appendChild(new_row);

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are several issues in the code. First of all, you've to change the value of the `id` attributes of the cloned elements, IDs are supposed to be unique. Then you're messing with the indices of the cells, at first the first cell of the new row is populated with `length`, then you're assuming cell[1] contains a select element, but there's an input element. Also `var options=inp1.innerHTML+options;` looks weird, it adds `undefined` at the end of the string. Maybe there's more, but a good start would be to fix the above issues.

Comment: ...  Uh ... actually `var options=inp1.innerHTML+options;` results in `undefinedundefined`, `inp1` is a HTMLCollection object ... Why do you override the clone in the first place, if you'd need a column for the lengths, the cell should be on every row, also on the first one. Just update that single cell of the clone, and append the clone row to the table.

Comment: I do know that is the problem I don't know how to make it correct. I am in need of some sample codes. More of how to create a select box in that <td> tag for each cloning rows.

Comment: Probably you need something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nyezuhm6/). Notice, that the fiddle implements `insRow` function only. Also, I've added `tbody` tag for adding the new rows properly. There are still some problems, at first, inline listeners are not recommended, you could use event delegation, and add only a single click listener to the table, and you could still achieve all the functionalities you currently have. Then I'm in doubt that all the id's are needed. Most likely you don't need any of them. Table elements already have ids, `rowIndex` and `cellIndex` are available.

Comment: [Another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyezuhm6/1/), without ids, implementing simple event delegation, includes also delete row method.

Comment: Thank you so much!!... I could understand my fault better and thank you for your code it is very much pleased.